# How to Split one row into two

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to create multiple columns based on subjects and Marks. data in column Name and Age will remain same for different subjects as shown
My first table is input data and the second one is desired output.

[image: Input Data]

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Hi! Can you share your data set using `dput(your_dataset)`?

Comment: See the `separate_rows()` function in the tidyr package